# Access the model in production.rb rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called SystemSettings with a name on and a value. It is where I store the majority of my configuration for my app. I need to be able to access it in my production.rb inside my rails 3.2 app. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Rails config such as `production.rb`is read before ActiveRecord is initialised you would need to use a callback:

```
Rails.application.configure do 
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
     config.custom_variable = SystemSettings.find_by(name: "Foo").value
  end
end
```

But since the callback executes later when ActiveRecord is ready you can't immediately use its value which is why your approach may be flawed due to  [race conditions](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition).

Unless you are building something like a CMS where you need to provide a user interface to edit system settings you will be better off using [environmental variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/ENV.html). They are immediately available from memory and do not have the overhead of a database query.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/initialization.html